# How to Change database of jbpm-6.1.0.Final and wildfly-8.1.0.Final from h2 to mysql

Tags: mysql, h2

I have tried my things convert the jbpm-6.1.0.Final and wildfly-8.1.0.Final **database** **h2** to **mysql** but I cannot be able to solve , kindly someone help me to do this.

Change in build.properties
*Comment the h2 code and enable mysql code*

```
  `# default is H2
   #H2.version=1.3.170
   #db.name=h2
   #db.driver.jar.name=${db.name}.jar
   #db.driver.download.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/${H2.version}/h2-${H2.version}.jar
  #other options are:
  #mysql
  db.name=jbpms
  db.driver.module.prefix=com/mysql
  db.driver.jar.name=${db.name}-connector-java.jar
  db.driver.download.url=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar`
```

I have performed every step in this url
http://manthapavankumar.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/configure-jbpm-with-mysql/

Comment: explain.. what have you tried, that will help other to understand your problem.

Comment: I have changed build.properties                                      # default is H2
#H2.version=1.3.170
#db.name=h2
#db.driver.jar.name=${db.name}.jar
#db.driver.download.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/${H2.version}/h2-${H2.version}.jar
#other options are:
#mysql
  db.name=jbpms
  db.driver.module.prefix=com/mysql
  db.driver.jar.name=${db.name}-connector-java.jar
  db.driver.download.url=https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`if you are not able to get the installer running only because of the driver, then let it install using h2 database. Once installed, follow the below steps,

1. download MySql driver for your server and place it in Jboss-Server?modules/system/layer/base/...
2. Change the satasource setting in jboss-server/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
3. Update the Hibernate db dialect inside the jbpm-console.war.
   a. jbpm-console.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
   b. Replace the dialect. (Refer to hibernate dialects document)
4. Remember that kie-workbench refers to the following datasource. Keep the name same or change it in persistence.xml if you have a datasource with different name.

   java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS